# Find all files with group write only permissions

Tags: files, permissions, find, freebsd

In the following example directory

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 user  testgroup  0 12 feb 12:00 file1
-rw-rw-r--  1 user  testgroup  0 12 feb 12:00 file2
-rw--w-r--  1 user  testgroup  0 12 feb 12:00 file3
-rw-r--r--  1 user  testgroup  0 12 feb 12:00 file4
-rw-rwxr--  1 user  testgroup  0 12 feb 12:00 file5
```

I would like to `find` all the files where *group* permissions are exactly `-w-`, that is `2` (only write permission).

I am using

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, versione 4.4.23(1)-release (amd64-portbld-freebsd12.0)
```

on FreeBSD 12. It is not GNU `find`.

My attempt was with

```
$ find . -perm -g+w
./file2
./file3
./file5
```

but this returns all the files having *at least* group write permissions; I would like to list instead the files whose group is only permitted to *write*. How to accomplish this?

Comment: have you tried `g=w`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes, the result is empty. No files found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add more conditions to exclude files with other permission bits set.

```
find . -perm -g+w ! -perm -g+r ! -perm -g+x
```

or (as proposed in steeldriver's comment)

```
find . -perm -g+w ! -perm /g+rx
```

Example:

```
$ ls -l file*
-rw-r--r-- 1 bodo bodo 0 Feb 12 12:50 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bodo bodo 0 Feb 12 12:50 file2
-rw--w-r-- 1 bodo bodo 0 Feb 12 12:50 file3
-rw--wxr-- 1 bodo bodo 0 Feb 12 12:50 file4
-rw-rwxr-- 1 bodo bodo 0 Feb 12 12:50 file5
$ find . -perm -g+w ! -perm -g+r ! -perm -g+x
./file3
$
$ find . -perm -g+w ! -perm /g+rx
./file3
$
```

Comment: +1, it works! It can surely be used this way. But I wonder if there is a direct way: it would be weird if there wasn't.

Comment: You can make it *slightly* more compact in GNU `find` using the `/perm` form e.g. `-perm -g+w ! -perm /g+rx`